# Google Maps API Giving error for Full and Partial Locations

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-maps-api-2

I came across a class for integrating google maps into my website at www.TrackTheSpraying.com.
Now to explain the concept here basically the end user submits a location (Full Address or City,State) than it pins the location on the map.

After a few submissions i get an error saying no address found for location.

can someone please help me and look at the code here and tell me what causes this....

I have been stumped for quite a while now.

Thank you !

```
<?php

/**
 * Allowed Controls:
 * GLargeMapControl - a large pan/zoom control used on Google Maps. Appears in the top left corner of the map.
 * GSmallMapControl - a smaller pan/zoom control used on Google Maps. Appears in the top left corner of the map.
 * GSmallZoomControl - a small zoom control (no panning controls) used in the small map blowup windows used to display driving directions steps on Google Maps.
 * GScaleControl - a map scale
 * GMapTypeControl - buttons that let the user toggle between map types (such as Map and Satellite)
 * GOverviewMapControl - a collapsible overview map in the corner of the screen
 */

  define(GoogleMapsKey, ''); 

  define( GLargeMapControl      , 'GLargeMapControl()');
  define( GSmallMapControl      ,    'GSmallMapControl()');
  define( GSmallZoomControl     , 'GSmallZoomControl()');
  define( GScaleControl         , 'GSCALEControl()');
  define( GMapTypeControl       , 'GMapTypeControl()');
  define( GOverviewMapControl , 'GOverviewMapControl()');

/**
 * API-Class for accessing Google Maps 
 */
class NXGoogleMapsAPI {

  // The Google Maps API Key
  var $apiKey;

  // Width and Height of the Control
  var $width;
  var $height;

  // GoogleMaps output div id
  var $divId;

  // ZoomFactor
  var $zoomFactor;

  // Map Center Coords
  var $centerX;
  var $centerY;

  // DragMarker
  var $dragX;
  var $dragY;

  // Address Array
  var $addresses;

  // GeoPoint Array
  var $geopoints;

  // Arrays with the controls that will be displayed
  var $controls;


  /**
   * Constructor
   *
   * @param string $apiKey The Google Maps API-Key for your domain.
   */
  function NXGoogleMapsAPI($apiKey="") {
    $this->apiKey = $apiKey;
    if ($this->apiKey == "") 
      $this->apiKey = GoogleMapsKey;
    $this->_initialize();
  }


  /**
   * Add an address-marker to the map. The address is resolved by the webbrowser.
   * with the Google Geocoder.
   *
   * @param string address which should be add. test with google maps
   * @param string HTML-Code which will be displayed when the user clicks the address
   * @param boolean Set the Center to this point(true) or not (false)
   */
  function addAddress($address, $htmlinfo, $setCenter=true) {
    $ar = array(addSlashes($address), addSlashes($htmlinfo), $setCenter);
    array_push($this->addresses, $ar);  
  }

  /**
   * Add a dragable marker to the map. Only one Drag-Marker is allowed!
   *
   * @param integer $longitude Longitude of the point
   * @param integer $latitude  Lattitude of the point
   */
  function addDragMarker($longitude, $latitude) {
    $this->dragX = $longitude;
    $this->dragY = $latitude;   
  }

  /**
   * Add a geopoint to the map. 
   *
   * @param integer Longitude of the point
   * @param integer Latitude of the point
   * @param string HTML-Code which will be displayed when the user clicks the address
   * @param boolean Set the Center to this point(true) or not (false)
   */  
  function addGeoPoint($longitude, $latitude, $htmlinfo, $setCenter) {
    $ar = array($longitude, $latitude, addSlashes($htmlinfo), $setCenter);
    array_push($this->geopoints, $ar);  
  }

  /**
   * Adds a control to the map
   *
   * @param control Control-Type. Allowed are the constants 
   * GLargeMapControl - a large pan/zoom control used on Google Maps. Appears in the top left corner of the map.
   * GSmallMapControl - a smaller pan/zoom control used on Google Maps. Appears in the top left corner of the map.
   * GSmallZoomControl - a small zoom control (no panning controls) used in the small map blowup windows used to display driving directions steps on Google Maps.
   * GScaleControl - a map scale
   * GMapTypeControl - buttons that let the user toggle between map types (such as Map and Satellite)
   * GOverviewMapControl - a collapsible overview map in the corner of the screen
   *      
   */      
  function addControl($control) {
    array_push($this->controls, $control);
  }

  /**
   * Set the ZoomFactor
   * The ZoomFactor is a value between 0 and 17
   *
   * @param integer $zoomFactor Value of the Zoom-Factor
   */
  function setZoomFactor($zoomFactor) {
     if ($zoomFactor > -1 && $zoomFactor < 18) {
       $this->zoomFactor = $zoomFactor;
     }
  }

  /**
   * Set the width of the map
   *
   * @param integer $width The Height in pixels
   */
  function setWidth($width) {
    $this->width = $width;
  }

  /**
   * Set the height of the map
   *
   * @param integer $height The Height in pixels
   */
  function setHeight($height) {
      $this->height = $height;
  }

  /**
   * Center the map to the coordinates
   *
   * @param integer $x Longitude
   * @param integer $y Latitude
   */
  function setCenter($x, $y) {
    $this->centerX = $x;
    $this->centerY = $y;
  }


  /**
   * Returns the HTML-Code, which must be placed within the <HEAD>-Tags of your page.
   *
   * @returns string The Code for the <Head>-Tag
   */
  function getHeadCode() {
    $out = '
 <style type="text/css">
     v\:* {
       behavior:url(#default#VML);
     }
    </style>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key='.$this->apiKey.'"  type="text/javascript"></script>';
   $out.= $this->_getGMapInitCode();
   return $out;
  }

  /**
   * Get the BodyCode and draw the map.
   *
   * @returns string Returns the code which is to be placed wight the <body>-tags.
   */
  function getBodyCode() {
    $out = '<div id="'.$this->divId.'" style="width:'.$this->width.'px;height:'.$this->height.'px;"></div>';    
    return $out;
  }

  /**
   * Get the code, which must be passed to the <body>-attribute onLoad.
   *
   * @returns string The onload Code
   */
  function getOnLoadCode() {
    $out = "initNXGMap(document.getElementById('$this->divId'));";
    return $out;
  }


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////// Internal functions /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  

  /** 
   * Compiles the Javascript to initialize the map.
   * Is automatically called, so do not call yourself.
   */
  function _getGMapInitCode() {
    $out = '
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var map = null;
var geocoder = null;
var center = null;
var updateX = null;
var updateY = null;
var marker = null;';

             // Add Geopoints Array
             $out.="\n";
      if ( count($this->geopoints) > 0 ) {          
        $out.= 'var geopoints = new Array(';
        for ($i=0; $i < count($this->geopoints); $i++) {
            $out.= ' new Array('.$this->geopoints[$i][0].','.$this->geopoints[$i][1].' ,"'.$this->geopoints[$i][2].'", ';
            // move to this address?
            if ($this->geopoints[$i][3]) {
                $out.='true';
            } else {
                $out.='false';
            }
            $out.=')';
            if ($i < (count($this->geopoints)-1)) $out.=', ';
        }
        $out.=");\n";
      } else {
          $out.="var geopoints = new Array();\n";
      }

             // Add Addresses Array      
      $out.="\n";
      if ( count($this->addresses) > 0 ) {          
        $out.= 'var addresses = new Array(';
        for ($i=0; $i < count($this->addresses); $i++) {
            $out.= ' new Array("'.$this->addresses[$i][0].'", "'.$this->addresses[$i][1].'", ';
            // move to this address?
            if ($this->addresses[$i][2]) {
                $out.='true';
            } else {
                $out.='false';
            }
            $out.=')';
            if ($i < (count($this->addresses)-1)) $out.=', ';
        }
        $out.=");\n";
      } else {
          $out.="var addresses = new Array();\n";
      }

        // Draw standard js-functions and initialization code.
        $out.='
function showAddresses() {
  for (i=0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
        showAddress(addresses[i][0], addresses[i][1], addresses[i][2]);
  } 
}

function showAddress(address, htmlInfo, moveToPoint) {
 if (geocoder) {
   geocoder.getLatLng(
     address,
     function(point) {
       if (!point) {
         alert("Location not found:" + address);
       } else {              
         if (moveToPoint) {
           map.setCenter(point, '.$this->zoomFactor.');
         }
         var marker = new GMarker(point);
         map.addOverlay(marker);
         if (htmlInfo != "") {
           GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
              marker.openInfoWindowHtml(htmlInfo);
           });              
         }
       }
     }
   );
  }
}

function showGeopoints() {
  for (i=0; i < geopoints.length; i++) {
        showGeopoint(geopoints[i][0], geopoints[i][1], geopoints[i][2], geopoints[i][3]);
  } 
}

function showGeopoint(longitude, latitude, htmlInfo, moveToPoint) {
  if (moveToPoint) {
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(longitude, latitude), '.$this->zoomFactor.');
  }
  var marker = new GMarker(new GLatLng(longitude, latitude));
  map.addOverlay(marker);
  if (htmlInfo != "") {
    GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
      marker.openInfoWindowHtml(htmlInfo);
    });              
     }   
}

function moveToGeopoint(index) {
    map.panTo(new GLatLng(geopoints[index][0], geopoints[index][1]));
}

function moveToAddress(index) {
  moveToAddressEx(addresses[index][0]); 
}

function moveToAddressEx(addressString) {
  if (geocoder) { 
   geocoder.getLatLng(
     addressString,
     function(point) {       
       if (!point) {
         alert("Location not found:" + addressString);
       } else {                                    
          center = point;
          map.panTo(point);           
       }
     });    
  }
}

function moveToAddressDMarker(addressString) {
  if (geocoder) { 
   geocoder.getLatLng(
     addressString,
     function(point) {       
       if (!point) {
         alert("Location not found:" + addressString);
       } else {                                    
          center = point;
          setZoomFactor(14);
          map.panTo(point);  
          addDragableMarker();         
       }
     });    
  }
}

function setZoomFactor(factor) {
      map.setZoom(factor);
}

function addDragableMarker() {
  if (!marker) {
    marker = new GMarker(center, {draggable: true});
    map.addOverlay(marker);

    GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend", function() {      
      var tpoint =  marker.getPoint();      
      document.getElementById(updateX).value = tpoint.lat();
      document.getElementById(updateY).value = tpoint.lng();              
  });

  } else {
    marker.setPoint(center);     
  }

  var tpoint =  marker.getPoint();      
  document.getElementById(updateX).value = tpoint.lat();
  document.getElementById(updateY).value = tpoint.lng();              
}

function initNXGMap(mapElement) {
    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        map = new GMap2(mapElement);        
        geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();';

      // Add controls to the map

      if (count($this->controls) > 0) {
        for ($i=0; $i<count($this->controls); $i++) {
          $out.=" map.addControl(new ".$this->controls[$i].");\n";
        }
      }

      // Center the map
      if (($this->centerX != -1000) && ($this->centerY != -1000)) {         
        $out.= '    map.setCenter(new GLatLng('.$this->centerX.', '.$this->centerY.'), '.$this->zoomFactor.');'."\n";       
      } else {
        $out.= '    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(0,0),1);'."\n";       
      }

      $out.='updateX="coordX"; updateY="coordY";';

      // Draw Dragmarker
      if (($this->dragX != 1000) && ($this->dragY != -1000)) {
        $out.='
          center = new GLatLng('.$this->dragY.','.$this->dragX.');
          map.setCenter(center, '.$this->zoomFactor.');
          marker = new GMarker(center, {draggable: true});
                map.addOverlay(marker);

                GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend", function() {      
                var tpoint =  marker.getPoint();      
                document.getElementById(updateX).value = tpoint.lat();
                document.getElementById(updateY).value = tpoint.lng();              
                });
        ';
      }

      // Add AddressPoints
            $out.="    showAddresses();\n";  
            // Add GeoPoints
            $out.="    showGeopoints();\n";

     $out.="\n";     
     $out.='    }
        }
     //]]>
     </script>';
    return $out;
  }

  /**
   * Initializes the standard values of the class. 
   * Is automatically called by the constructor.
   */
  function _initialize() {
    $this->width            = 800;
    $this->height       = 600;
    $this->divId        = 'map';
    $this->zoomFactor = 14;
    $this->centerX    = -1000;
    $this->centerY    = -1000;
    $this->dragX            = -1000;
    $this->dragY            = -1000;
    $this->addresses  = array();
    $this->geopoints  = array();
    $this->controls   = array();
  }

}

?>
```

Comment: Looks like that code is using the deprecated Google Maps Javascript API v2. That version should not be used for new code, as it is not supported, it has been turned off and replaced with a wrapper for v3.

Comment: it appears that i am i need of some time to write my own or find a new Class. Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/v2tov3